# cocos2d game center and leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have write the code like bellow

```
    - (void)leaderboard {
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    currentLeaderBoard = kLeaderboardID;
    if (leaderboardController != NULL) 
    {
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self; 
        leaderboardController.category = currentLeaderBoard;
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime; 
        tempVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:tempVC.view];
        [tempVC presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
    }
}


- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

having the warning like bellow:

```
Assigning to 'id<GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'HelloWorldLayer *'
```

it also showing on log view:

```
warning: class 'HelloWorldLayer' does not implement the 'GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate' protocol
```

I count find out why it is. and even when the game center leader board goes out then the menu becomes disable.
I count continue with the game everything becomes disable.

sorry for the post editing i have solved the second part  of the problem by myself.
 I have shifted the leaderboard view in another view.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the class interface and add GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate to the list of implemented protocols:

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
```

The rest of the question I could not understand, can you paraphrase?